# Using predict() to predict response variable in test dataset

Tags: r, prediction, predict

Question: What r code should one use to predict a response variable in a completely separate test data set (not the test data set drawn from the original data set from which the training data set has been drawn) that doesn't have a response variable?

I have been stuck on this for two days and any help is highly appreciated!

My training set has 100 observations and 27 variables. "units" is the response variables. The test set has 6000 observations and 26 variables. I am showing only a part of both data sets to keep the length of my question manageable.

I am using ISLR and MASS packages.

**Training set:**

```
age V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  units
10  1    3   0   5   5   5   5828
7   4    5   4   4   1   2   2698
5   6    6   4   7   8  10   2578
4   4    5   4   4   1  3    2548
15  3    5   4   4   2  5    9922
5   2    4   4   5   1  3    6791
```

**Test set:**

```
age V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6
2   3   4   4   4   2   2
2   2   5   4   5   2   3
10  5   4   4   4   1   3
4   15  7   6   3   4   8
7   2   5   4   4   2   2
4   6   5   4   5   2   2
18  2   5   4   5   1   3
6   3   5   5   6   4   5
```

**R Code:**

```
library(ISLR)
library(MASS)

train = read.csv(".../train.csv", header = T)

train.pca = train[c(-27)]

pr.out = prcomp(train.pca, scale = TRUE, center = TRUE, retx = TRUE) # Conducting PCA  

plot(pr.out, type = 'l')

summary(pr.out)

pred.tr = predict(pr.out, newdata = train) # Predicting on the train data

dat.tr = cbind(train, pred.tr) # Appending PCA output to the train data

glm.fit.pca = glm(units ~ PC2 + PC3 + PC4 + PC5 + 
                      PC6 + PC7 + PC8 + PC9 + PC10 + 
                      PC11 + PC12 + PC13 + PC14 + PC15, 
                      data = dat.tr) # Conducting glm on train data with PCs

test = read.csv(".../test.csv", header = T) # Reading in test data

pred.test = predict(pr.out, newdata = test, type = "response") # Predicting 

# on test data. With this code, I get the following error message - "Error  
# in predict.prcomp(pr.out, newdata = y, type = "response") : 
# 'newdata' does not have named columns matching one or more of the original
# columns" I understand why because the test set doesn't have the response 
# variable
```

So I tried the following:

```
pred.test = predict(pr.out, newdata = test) # This doesn't give me any error

dat.test = cbind(test_numr, pred.test) # Appending PCA output to test data
```

I don't understand how I can conduct a glm on the test data, the way I did on train data because test data set doesn't have a response variable (i.e., "units"). I tried initializing the response variable in the test data by doing the following to add the response variable in the test data set:

```
dat.test$units = rep(0, nrow(dat.test))
```

Now when I try to run the glm model on the dat.test data set, I get all zeros. I can understand why but I don't understand what changes should I make to my code to get the predictions for the test data set.

Any guidance is highly appreciated! Thank you!

EDIT: I edited and ran the code again based on the comment from @csgillespie. I still have the same issue. Thanks for catching the error!

Comment: Your 'glm` formula looks odd. You are trying to predict units, using PCs that already contain units.

Comment: You have at least two issues I'm able to pick out. 1) you're applying `predict` to the `pr.out` object and not your glm object. 2) Even before you do predict on your test data, you'll need to apply the same PCA transform to it so that you just get the components (like you do for the train data)

Comment: @Tchotchke, appreciate your input! What you said makes sense. I will try your method and update.

Comment: @Tchotchke, one question - by conducting the PCA separately on both test and training set, how can I apply `predict(glm, newdata = test)` on my test data as the glm model was based on the training data and it had different independent variables (the independent variables were the PCs from the PCA done on training data)?

Comment: You want to apply it to the train set, then apply the same transformation to the test set (so that you end up with the same number of principal components). Then you'll have the same number of features in your test set, so you'll be able to use that to get a prediction. If you have questions about PCA, you may want to consider posting on Cross Validated, which is a better forum for machine learning methodology questions.